# Why will jquery datatable reset the displayStart when first rendered

Tags: jquery, datatables

```
// the function that has to be runned
function _fnInitialise ( settings )
{
  ......
  _fnReDraw( settings );
  ......
}

// the holdPosition decide whether to keep _iDisplayStart
function _fnReDraw( settings, holdPosition )
{
  ......
  if ( holdPosition !== true ) {
    settings._iDisplayStart = 0;
  }
  ......
}

// so the displayStart or iDisplayStart of my options will be reset 



var __reload = function ( settings, holdPosition, callback )
```

HoldPosition is a param that can decide whether keeping the page info(displayStart and pageLength) when reloading.

```
function _fnInitialise ( settings )
```

_fnInitalise will run when drawing the table for the first time. The page info will be reset in this function without any param like __reload. So I can not set default displayStart.

Answer (score 0):

"stateSave" can solve my problem.The displayStart will be remember into localStorage or sessionStorage if "stateSave" set to true.The key is `Datatable_${tableId}_${url}`.I can get the info outsides Datatables.